# Quarkus does not recognize my method of applying the filter

Tags: filter, quarkus, interceptor, quarkus-reactive

I have the following filter:

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class FilterHTTP implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FilterHTTP.class);

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        // Perform validation of the request here
        LOG.debug("Ingreso al metodo filter");

        //************OBTENIENDO LOS HEADERS*******************

        MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers = requestContext.getHeaders();
        for( String headerName : headers.keySet()){
            String headerValue = headers.getFirst(headerName);
            LOG.debug("HEADER  - CLAVE : {} - VALOR : {}",headerName, headerValue);
            //Do something with the header
        }
        //************OBTENIENDO LOS QUERY-PARAMS*******************
        UriInfo uriInfo = requestContext.getUriInfo();
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();

        // iterate through the query parameters
        for (String paramName : queryParams.keySet()) {
            List<String> paramValues = queryParams.get(paramName);
            LOG.debug("QUERY PARAM : {}" , paramValues);
            // do something with the parameter
        }


        /*
         ************ VALIDACIONES ******************+
         */
        boolean valid = validateRequest(requestContext);
        if (!valid) {
            LOG.debug("Ingreso al metodo if del filter  - BAD REQUEST");
            // If the request is not valid, abort the request with an error response
            Response response = Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("Invalid request").build();
            requestContext.abortWith(response);
        }

    }

    private boolean validateRequest(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        // Perform validation of the request here
        // Return true if the request is valid, false otherwise

        return true;
    }


}
```

- And I have the following controller with two methods:

```
@Path("/accounts/retrieve")
public class SavingsAccountController implements AccountsAPI {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SavingsAccountController.class);

    @Inject
    SavingAccountService savingAccountService;

    @Override
    public Response getAllAccounts(@HeaderParam("X-Channel-Code")   String xChannelCode) {

        LOG.debug("X CHANNEL : {}", xChannelCode);
        LOG.debug("Ingresó al controller");

        List<AccountRetrieveResInnerDTO> accounts = savingAccountService.getSavingsAccounts();
        boolean hasData = accounts != null && !accounts.isEmpty();

        if (hasData) {
            return Response.ok(accounts).build();
        }
        return Response.noContent().build();
    }

    @GET
    @Produces({ "application/json" })
    @Path("/hello")
    @Interceptors(FilterHTTP.class)
    public String hello() {
        LOG.debug("Ingreso al metodo hello");
        return "Hello from RESTEasy Reactive";
    }

}
```

I did it this way so that my filter is executed only when the 'hello()' method is executed, but when I run the 'getAllAccounts' method, my interceptor is executed, does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

I have tried '@Interceptors(FilterHTTP.class)',
adding annotations like '@ExcludeDefaultInterceptors' but still my filter executes for any method in my controller, I would appreciate if someone has some idea.

I know about the existence of @Bindings but I can't use them due to internal requirements.

Comment: `@Interceptors` is not used in JAX-RS / Jakarta REST

Comment: There is another way  to achieve this ?

Comment: You will have to use `@Context ResourceInfo` in your `FilterHTTP` and use it to only execute the filter for methods you care about